# nginx redirect /videos/(.*)/(.*).html to /video/(.*)/(.*)

Tags: html, nginx, http-status-code-404, redirect

hello i really need your help abour nginx redirection. So i ve this old url:
http://www.website.com/videos/bla-bla.html (url rewriting) and i want to redirect 301 to 
http://www.website.com/video/bla-bla
i did it with php but i ve a 404 error because .html file doesn t exist.
So can you help me? i ve searched every where in the web and i can t find an answer.
:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like this:

```
rewrite ^/videos/(.*)\.html$ /video/$1 permanent;
```